# Read a matrix from a txt and store it in a 2D array in java

Tags: java, matrix

So I'm trying put a matrix from a txt file into a variable and I have though about using an Array called `value[][]`.

for example the file could be:

```
0 2 8 1
4 1 6 2
2 1 4 7
2 4 7 9
```

And the value of `value[2][1]` would be 6.
Feel free to suggest me another format, like, for example, using commas to separate the numbers if it's more effective.

I will always use square matrices (2X2, 3X3, 4X4...) and I need to get the number of rows (or columns) from the filte and then store it into another variable called **nMatrix**.

And I'm not sure about how to read the file and then store the correct numbers in the correct cells of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with undefined matrix length:

```
int[][] value = null;
//you can use relative path or full path here
File file = new File("file-name.txt");
try {
    Scanner sizeScanner = new Scanner(file);
    String[] temp = sizeScanner.nextLine().split(" ");
    sizeScanner.close();
    int nMatrix = temp.length;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    value = new int[nMatrix][nMatrix];
    for (int i = 0; i < nMatrix; i++) {
        String[] numbers = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
        for (int j = 0; j < nMatrix; j++) {
            value[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[j]);
        }
    }
    scanner.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I dont put the value of nMatrix in the method, I need to get the value of nMatrix from the matrix in the txt

Comment: It's fixed now ;)

Comment: with the fix it works perfectly. and it doesn't use bufferedReader and similar things that looked very difficult.

Answer (score 2):

So the trick is to get your file read properly so make sure you get the path down right. There are several ways to get to a file on your file system but I chose the full path option.

This solution gives you flexibility later on.

```
public class ReadMatrix {

private static final String FILENAME = "/Users/username/Developer/Workspaces/java/SandboxPlayingAroundId/src/main/java/matrix.txt";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    FileReader fileReader = null;
    Map<Integer, String[]> matrixMap = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        fileReader = new FileReader(FILENAME);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String currentLine;
        int columnCounter = 0;

        while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] rowNumbers = currentLine.split(" ");
            matrixMap.put(columnCounter++, rowNumbers);
        }

        //print number of rows
        System.out.println(matrixMap.size());

        //print number of columns for nth row (2nd since our indexes are 0 based)
        int n = 1;
        System.out.println(matrixMap.get(n).length);

        //print element on nXm (1st since our indexes are 0 based
        int m = 0;
        System.out.println(matrixMap.get(n)[m]); //will print 4

    } catch (IOException ioEx) {
        ioEx.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (bufferedReader != null)
                bufferedReader.close();
            if (fileReader != null)
                fileReader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use a method like readFile(String theFileName)
{
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(theFileName);
     int[][] matrix = new int[someNumber][someNumber]
     try{
         for(int val = 0; val < matrix.length; val++)
          {
            for(int val2 = 0; val2< matrix[val].length; val++)
              {
                 matrix[val][val2] = scan.next();
              }
          }
        }
scan.close();
}
```

Comment: But how can I get the number of rows/columns then?